# Javascript: Checking if function exists in sibling frame before calling

Tags: javascript, frames

I have two frames in a window. Frame A and frame B.

I want to call a function which is in frame A from frame B. To do this I use:

```
 parent.frames['mainframe'].myfunction();
```

The catch is that the function may not actually exist in frame A.

I want to check if it exists before calling.

I tried this but got a JS error.

```
if ( typeof parent.frames['mainframe'].myfunction == 'function' ) { 
        //function_name is a function
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Update:

You are all correct- the actual code I was running was typeof parent.frames['mainframe'].myfunction() with parenthesis. Sorry :/ What do I do about best answer?

Comment: And the JS error you got was ... ???

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: If that `typeof` check succeeds and you call the function inside that `if` (or only when that `if` succeeded), then it would work. Is this **all** the relevant code?

Comment: Yes, I would call the function inside the if. But if the even what is written here throws an error

Comment: That's a strange error considering you aren't calling any functions. Are you sure you're checking for the existence of the function before calling it? Have you forgotten a call to `myfunction` elsewhere in the code?

Comment: Always use the strict equality operator `===` when working with `typeof`.

Comment: You would have to give more info, perhaps show an example of your site that is having the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should definitely work. It does appear that `myfunction` isn't in the global scope on the child window. When you refer to `parent.frames['mainframe']` you are essentially referencing the `window` object in the 'mainframe' iframe. Here's a JSFiddle where the child function is explicitly set on the `window` object and works just fine.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qbe6y130/1/)

Comment: sorry, I lost you. How can i check if the function exists in the sibling frame?

Comment: You're doing it right, actually. There is something else strange going on in your code. Is there any other relevant javascript?